# Angular - How to use an attribute's value in a custom directive?

Tags: angularjs

Super Angular rookie here.

Got a custom directive to create an element that will write a value of an attribute into a span :

```
myApp.directive("myDirective", function(){
    return {
        restrict : "E",
        template : "<span>{{ dirCtrl.dirText }}</span>",
        controller : function($attrs){
            this.dirText = $attrs.dirText;
        },  
        controllerAs : "dirCtrl"
    };
});
```

To test it if a write

```
<my-directive dir-text="Test 1 2 3"></my-directive>
```

Output is `Test 1 2 3` as expected but if i use more than once

```
<my-directive dir-text="Test 1 2 3"></my-directive><br>
<my-directive dir-text="Test 4 5 6"></my-directive>
```

Output is

```
Test 4 5 6
Test 4 5 6
```

but i expect it to be

```
Test 1 2 3
Test 4 5 6
```

So, what do i do wrong?

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8q2n8fLz/4/)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to use `scope:true,` (create child scope) or `scope:{},`(create isolated scope) option in your directive, otherwise bothe the directive instances use the same scope and setting `dirCtrl.dirText` is also on the same scope so last one overwrites any other previous instance set values. Using a childscope or isolated scope creates a scope for that directive itself which is more appropriate as well in your case.  *Whenever you set a property on the scope from a directive it is always advisable to create a scope for the directive (unless that is really the intention), because often you don't want to pollute the current scope where the directive is in.*

```
.directive("myDirective", function(){
    return {
        restrict : "E",
        scope:true,
        template : "<span>{{ dirCtrl.dirText }}</span>",
        controller : function($attrs){
            this.dirText = $attrs.dirText;
        },
        controllerAs : "dirCtrl"
    };
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2bfv32z1/)**

Comment: Wow. Just like that huh? Thank you very much.